# Why while(true) is an infinite loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have tried to search this question in stackoverflow but did not find it. Feel free to delete this post (please link me too...) if this is posted elsewhere.

I just started programming with C and learnt that

```
while(true)
{
}
```

forms an infinite loop.

To my understanding, this means the function executes with the condition of being "true". But what does this mean? Is the condition always set as "true" in the first place?

May some one please explain!

Comment: Yes, the condition is always evaluated as true.

Comment: Please don't randomly downvote. This is a valid (albeit novice) question.

Comment: Too bad we can't down vote comments.

Comment: ...and yes CWL, it's unfair, but your question is being punished for David's ridiculousness.

Comment: CWL, you're probably just overthinking this. It is literally as simple as a condition that is always true.

Comment: You would be better off using a Google search. searching for `c while statement` returns a link to MSDN documentation which explains how the while statement works, and it is pretty clear that using `true` as an expression is going to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: As indicated by @DeanOC, `while` is not a function, but a statement. Please make sure that you understand the difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an explanation of a tautology.

Comment: Key misconception: 'while' is not a function, it's a language construct.

Comment: Well, thinking about it, and giving reasonable consideration, and noting that this is a Q&A site for enthusiast and/or professional developers, I will downvote, and not randomly.

Comment: For the sake of interpreting those lines you should understand that you're not calling any function but `while(true)` will be executed 'atomically'. There's no function call involved.

Comment: Why the hell was this downvoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
while (a)
{
    // b
}
```

If `a` is true, then block `b` will execute. This will keep repeating until `a` is not true.

If `a` is replaced with the constant value `true`, then `a` will never be false so the loop will never quit.

Answer (score 5):

The while loop loops through a block of code as long as a specified condition is true.

```
while (condition) {
    code block to be executed
}
```

Here **true** evaluates always to **true** (true == true) so it will be an endless loop

```
while(true) { } // always evaluates to true
```

same as

```
while(true == true) { }
```

same goes for **1**  and other `non falsy` values

Answer (score 3):

Because 'true' is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how do you propose that condition ever turns false?

Think of that line as synonymous with:

```
while(true == true) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

A while loop is in this kind of format

```
While(Condition){ 
code to execute
}
other code
```

A while loop evaluates the expression in the condition.

When the condition in the While loop evaluates true, it runs the "code to execute" until the closing brace and then its check the condition again. And when the condition is true, it does the loop again.

If its false "other code" will be Executed so It will when the condition never changes also always stays true its an infinite Loop

In C you can also write one instead of true  so this loop,

```
While(1){}
```

is also an Infinite Loop

Comment: Please re-spell, re-capitalize, punctuate, and paragraph this illegible mess.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm)

> A while loop statement in C programming language repeatedly executes a target statement as long as a given condition is true.

Now this means that the loop will continue as long as the condition is true.

But then, you would ask "when is the condition true" ?

To explain that, take a simple example

```
int a = 5 , b = 2 ;
while ( a > b )
  {
     printf ( " %d " , a );
  }
```

All [Relational Operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_relational_operators.htm)  ( like `<` `>` `==` `!=` , etc ) return true if their condition is met, so that is how this works.

So, the condition `a > b` returns true ( or 1 ) if `a` is greater than `b`. ( Note that this is an infinite loop because the value of `b` will always be less than `a` )

The while loop will continue as long as the condition is non zero.

This means something like

```
while ( 2 ) 
  {
  }
```

is also an infinite loop ( because 2 is non zero, and hence true ) .

But if it was

```
while ( 0 )
  {
  }
```

0 is equal to false, and thus, the loop is not executed.

But then , this code

```
int a = 5 , b = 2 ;
while ( a > b )
  {
     printf ( " %d " , a );
     b++;
  }
```

is not an infinite loop because after executing the loop a few times, `b` will become 6, which is greater than `a`, and hence, the condition `( a > b )` will return false, and the loop will stop.